# Making a matrix in python 3 without numpy using inputs

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, input, range, sequence

I want to have two inputs : a,b or x,y whatever...
When the user inputs say,

```
3 5
```

Then the shell should print a matrix with 3 rows and 5 columns also it should fill the matrix with natural numbers( number sequence starting with 1 and not 0).
Example::

IN :`2 2`

OUT:`[1,2]
     [3,4]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your objective is only to get the output in that format

```
n,m=map(int,input().split())
count=0
for _ in range(0,n):
    list=[]
    while len(list) > 0 : list.pop()
    for i in range(count,count+m):
        list.append(i)
        count+=1
    print(list)
```

Comment: This hits very close to what I want! Thank You Srinabh Sir!

Comment: What if I want to do it without brackets? like :: 1, 2/n 3,4

Comment: change the last print statement to  print(*list)

Answer (score 0):

Numpy library provides reshape() function that does exactly what you're looking for.

```
from numpy import * #import numpy, you can install it with pip
    n = int(input("Enter number of rows: ")) #Ask for your input, edit this as desired.
    m = int(input("Enter number of columns: "))
    x = range(1, n*m+1) #You want the range to start from 1, so you pass that as first argument.
    x = reshape(x,(n,m)) #call reshape function from numpy
    print(x) #finally show it on screen
```

**EDIT**

If you don't want to use numpy as you pointed out in the comments, here's another way to solve the problem without any libraries.

```
n = int(input("Enter number of rows: ")) #Ask for your input, edit this as desired.
m = int(input("Enter number of columns: "))
x = 1 #You want the range to start from 1
list_of_lists = [] #create a lists to store your columns
for row in range(n):
    inner_list = []   #create the column
    for col in range(m):
        inner_list.append(x) #add the x element and increase its value
        x=x+1
    list_of_lists.append(inner_list) #add it

for internalList in list_of_lists: #this is just formatting.
    print(str(internalList)+"\n")
```

Comment: I edited the answer. The code without libraries is below it :) Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to give a try without using numpy library.

```
row= int(input("Enter number of rows"))
col= int(input("Enter number of columns"))
count= 1
final_matrix= []
for i in range(row):
    sub_matrix= []
    for j in range(col):
        sub_matrix.append(count)
        count += 1
    final_matrix.append(sub_matrix)
```

Comment: It says 'mat' is not defined.

Comment: I'm sorry there was a typo. I have edited the code. Hope this time it works. @ WISERDIVISOR